# Erro de tradução na legenda do filme Avatar(2009)?

Tags: tradução-inglês, termos-em-inglês

Eu estava assistindo novamente ao filme Avatar(2009) e logo na cena de abertura do filme estranhei a tradução na legenda em português. O áudio original em inglês era:

''When I was lying there in the VA hospital with a big hole blown through the middle of my life,I started having these dreams of flying. I was free.''

Tradução na legenda:''Quando eu estava de cama no hospital dos veteranos com um buraco enorme no meio da minha vida, eu comecei a ter esses sonhos de voar. Eu era livre.''

Me parece que houve um erro de tradução de ''big hole blown'' para ''um buraco enorme'' ou eu estou enganado? Pois por mais que o personagem estivesse sendo metafórico, traduzir literalmente o trecho para ''um buraco enorme no meio da minha vida'' não parece nem um pouco natural em português ao dizer que algo muito grave tinha acontecido com a vida dele(provavelmente o acidente na guerra que o deixou paralítico) a menos que essa fosse realmente a intenção do personagem ao dizer um ''buraco enorme'', mas se assim fosse também não seria uma maneira natural de dizer em inglês e a fala seria considerada mal feita para um contexto metafórico.

Se ''blow a hole'' se tratava aqui de uma expressão idiomática(cujo significado se refere a estragar/arruinar um plano ou idéia,às vezes sendo uma collocation), como tal, a tradução da legenda deveria ter se adequado ao contexto.
Se eu estiver certo, a tradução próxima poderia ter sido ''Quando eu estava deitado no hospital dos veteranos, com um estrago enorme feito no meio da minha vida, eu comecei ter esses sonhos de voar. Eu era livre.''

A tradução na legenda está mesmo incorreta ou o texto do áudio original é que não foi bem escrito ao ser metafórico?

Comment: Ó, Stafusa! Moderador célico! Dai-me silêncio nesta indagação ubíqua no que percebo. Eis uma pergunta foras das regras maiores, por tratar-se de tradução, ou dentro?! Obrigado, Senhor Stafusa! Vós sois grande e bom!

Comment: Ó grande inquisitor @Schilive que maior e melhor sois, não estou a altura da honra de vossa pergunta — aos cuidados de nossa estimada e admirável comunidade a questão deixarei. :) Ou seja: se votarem para fechar, não vou intervir, mas enquanto o site não for inundado por perguntas do tipo, não vejo necessidade de fechar com o martelo da moderação, ainda mais quando a pergunta demonstra esforço.

Comment: @Schilive Tradução **ao português** pode, é para o inglês que não pode.

Comment: @Lambie BTW, ótima resposta. +1

Answer (score 3):

A tradução está correta. Eis a razão:

**Blow a hole in something** é uma expressão *que quer dizer outra coisa* e aqui essa expressão idiomática não funciona.

I blew a hole **in this argument**. Ou seja, dar as razões de porque um argumento não é válido. Destruir um argumento de um interlocutor.

O interlocutor aqui está falando com o leitor.

Literal: the bomb *blew a huge hole through* the building.
A bomba **atravessou o edifício criando** um buraco enorme quando explodiu. Por exemplo.

Nessa frase: ''When I was lying there in the VA hospital with a big hole blown through the middle of my life" *o leitor pensa que vai ler*: blew a hole through my leg ou arm. Só que o escritor é esperto e mudou a metáfora para vida do cara. Tudo bem. Muito criativo.

**Um buraco enorme no meio da minha vida** dá conta da metáfora.

Poderia ter escrito: com um buraco enorme atravessando minha vida

Claro, se perde a ideia do inglés de "blow (up)", neste caso blow through his life. Não vejo como ficar com a ideia de blow through sem a coisa ficar bem pesada: Com um buraco enorme no meio da minha vida resultando de uma explosão.

*É tambem preciso ver que os tradutores precisam prestar atenção ao comprimento das frases*. **Elas/eles não sempre dispõem do espaço para fazer uma frase mas comprida que seria mas completa**.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142254/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-erro-de-traducao-na-legenda-do-filme-avatar2009).

Comment: @Schilive I'm sure it is "extended". :)

Comment: @Southman Acho que já chega.